# Creating an option clash between custom class options

Tags: document-classes, package-options, class-options, option-clash

In my custom LaTeX class, I've created some different options, such as different font sizes, `11pt`, `12pt` and `13pt`, and paper sizes, such as `a4paper` and `letterpaper`. However, only one option from each group should be given, like the following.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{class} % or
\documentclass[13pt, a4paper]{class} % but never
\documentclass[12pt, 13pt]{class}
```

The last one shouldn't be used since it specifies the font size twice, which would create an undesirable effect. What I would want instead is that if two or more commands which *clash* are provided, such as in  `\documentclass[12pt, 13pt]{class}`, my class delivers an error message using `\ClassError`. How would this be done?

Just in case I would need to use conditional 'if' statements, please try to give code using the style of statement used for the `etoolbox` package, it's what I use and find easiest.

Answer (score 4):

Building on my previous answer, here is a way:

```
\ProvidesClass{akuritsu}

\newif\ifaku@sizegiven
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{2}\aku@sizegiventrue}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{1}\aku@sizegiventrue}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{0}\aku@sizegiventrue}
\DeclareOption{12pt-standard}{\def\aku@ptsize{2}}

\ExecuteOptions{12pt-standard}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\PassOptionsToClass{1\aku@ptsize pt}{article}

\LoadClass{article}

\ifaku@sizegiven
  \ClassError{akuritsu}
     {Multiple font size options}
     {You have specified two or more options among `10pt', `11pt' or `12pt'}
\fi
```

You have to use a different default option, as otherwise the error message would be issued for a single font size option.